# Why are all screens of SpaceX dragon control panel blue themed?

Tags: color-scheme

All the interfaces used in SpaceX dragon have a blue themed interface. I'm just curious as to why specifically **blue** and **dark** interface? 
Apart from blue being a sign of trust, not sure what other factors in terms of UI/UX decide that.

[image]

Comment: I am interested to know how it compares to other space shuttle/pod control panels - hopefully there is a 'space' related reason to make it interesting!

Comment: I can think of Psychological reasons, as well as to avoid eye strain with too much luminosity... assumptions, though :)

Comment: Well if not blue, then what other colour could it be? (assuming we discount white/black) Red and green are out for obvious reasons. Yellow, if you have never tried, plays havoc on your eyes (serious, you see things that just aren't there!). So that only really leaves blue or purple.... which would you pick?

Comment: I wondered how influenced they were by the screen designs in the movie 2001...

Comment: https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2018/04/learning-about-the-future-from-2001-a-space-odyssey-fifty-years-later/

Answer (score 3):

Regarding [dark mode](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/dark-mode/):

> The researchers found significant thinning of this membrane when participants read text presented in light mode and significant thickening when reading text presented in dark mode. The thinning was more pronounced in participants who already had myopia.
>
> This result seems to suggest that, even though performance in light mode may be better in the short term, there may be a long-term cost associated with it.

However, it may also be borrowed from aviation guidelines. In the following post, there is a [discussion regarding white displays affecting night vision.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51871/why-are-cockpit-instruments-white-on-black-dials)

The [FAA guidelines](https://www.faa.gov/data_research/research/med_humanfacs/oamtechreports/2000s/media/0117.pdf) also has a brief section regarding luminance (3.2.3):

> Information should be readable over a wide range of ambient illumination under all foreseeable conditions relative to the operating environment.

It’s also hard to say the displays are blue. It might be because of the angle of the photo and the composition of the display itself. There are photos where the interface [appears dark grey / black](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6a/22/ef/6a22efd06d55b38936195d21e92aa7aa.jpg). Additionally, we also don’t know if the interface has other contrast settings to perform in different light environments.